# Why is my python GAE create_login_url redirecting user to google settings personal info page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect, jinja2

I'm using `create_login_url` like before, put the result of `create_login_url(any_url_of_my_app)`, to the javascript block so the page could use it. This works fine locally and worked fine before I believe.

However I just found yesterday that **google accounts** would redirect users to `https://www.google.com/settings/personalinfo` instead of the url I gave it after user logged in.

The login url it returned is like,
`https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&amp;passive=true&amp;continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://name.of.my.project.appspot.com/&amp;ltmpl=gm&amp;shdf=ChULEgZhaG5hbWUaCWd1ZXNzMjAxNAwSAmFoIhSWGiv4SgCRz7RQd7_b7shxZMaj_CgBMhT1jp44vsCkuJhUxaZgPHWB4Z_2TQ`

It looks like google accounts would redirect user to `appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin` and then that conflogin page would redirect user to my app page second.

I tried to connect to `appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin` directly but got a 500 error back.

Eventually I locked down to jinja2 which is doing some unnecessary UriEncoding for me. Anyway that I could turn that off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flask.Markup` to wrap around the string so it won't be escaped.

```
from flask import Markup
#...
def main():
    #...
    login_url = Markup(users.create_login_url(any_url_of_my_app))
    #...
    return render_template(template_file_name, login_url=login_url)
```

And use this `login_url` for `render_template`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with Django, and similarly, adding `autoescape=False` to `Context` will fix this.

```
def home(request):
  context = Context({
    'login_url': users.create_login_url('/')
  }, autoescape=False)

  template = loader.get_template('index.html')
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```